# Custom html attributesi in Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I know that in the html helper BeginForm available in asp.net mvc there is a param called htmlAttributes. How can I use it witouth specify the previous params? I don't want to override the default action/method values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing null as the value of the BeginForm function will apply the default params value

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new{title = "title"}))
{ 
    ...
}
```

which outputs:

```
<form action="/" class="someclass" method="post">
</form>
```

It's not exaclty what you wanted and it's not pretty. You do have to specify the FormMethod.

Or add the attributes you need via jQuery.

Comment: I found that passing in the params null apply the default values... Thank you anyway